# Document is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, document

I keep getting this error when I am watching videos and copying the code exactly.

```js
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, dice

scores = [0,0]
roundScore = 0
activePlayer = 0

dice = console.log (Math.floor(Math.random() * (6) + 1))
console.log(dice)

document.querySelector('#current-0').textContent = dice
```

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at init (/Users/Nikolas/Desktop/JS/app.js:79:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Nikolas/Desktop/JS/app.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

[image: html file]

Comment: Are you trying to open the `.js` file in Node.js?

Comment: You're getting this error because you're running JavaScript in the **server-side** Node environment where the DOM (`document`, `window`, etc) isn't available - that's why you're getting the error. (i.e. NodeJS **should not be running `app.js`**). I don't know why NodeJS is running `app.js` - please post your command-line you use to start the webserver and any bower, webpack, or gulp tasks.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
      //Do my stuff
    });
});
```

Instead of above code call this

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //call your script.js function from here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `document` is have to be defined initially (even your code uses it: `$(document)`)

Comment: How do I define it initially?

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the OP isn't using jQuery (and we shouldn't using jQuery anymore anyway).